# Is there a possibility to print a physical receipt through just coding?

Tags: java, netbeans, printing

I am going to be soon writing a program for an EPOS system as part of a coursework/practise code. I am trying to think in advance what my user might want me to include in the code and suspect that they might want me to have a receipt printed as part of their requirements.

I've had a look around the internet and haven't really found a solution to this, I am coding in Java (using NetBeans IDE), and was wondering if any of you could possbily assist me in this situation.

I would want to include some things like the list of items selected/sold, total price and possibly the time of transaction.

Thanks for any assistance you can give :)

Comment: what do you mean by physical report. you just get it printed ?

Comment: yes, that is surely possible.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can consider an approach with ActiveX component. But of course you can choose an another one.

Function will be called on UI.

```
function print(data) {
   try {
      var printer = new ActiveXObject("LocalPrinterComponent.Printer");
      if (printer) {
         printer.print(data);
      } else {
        alert("error");
      }
   } catch (ex) {
      .....
   }
}
```